# Swift Firebase - Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error which I can't figure out how to fix:

```
Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal
```

I've searched on the internet but failed to find an answer. Here's my code:

```
struct Sweet {

let key:String!
let content:String!
let addedByUser:String!
let itemReft:FIRDatabaseReference?

init (content:String, addedByUser:String, key:String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.content = content
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.itemReft = nil
}

init (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    itemReft = snapshot.ref

    if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let postContent = dict["content"] as? String {
        content = postContent
    } else {
        content = ""
    }

    if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let postUser = dict["addedByUser"] as? String {
        addedByUser = postUser
    } else {
        addedByUser = ""
    }

}

func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
    return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser]
}
```

The error happens at this line:

```
return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser]
```

I've been following this tutorial [iOS Swift Tutorial: Get started with Firebase and an App like Twitter](https://youtu.be/D0MuaFzoxng?t=33m57s)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why are the `String` properties optional and the initializer values all non-optional? That's a typical misuse of implicit unwrapped optionals. If this is Swift 3 use `Any` but the type is doubtless `[String:String]`.

Comment: So should i make then optional?

Comment: No, make them non-optional. Remove the exclamation marks.

Comment: Ok I tried, the project successfully compiled but not now when try to send to firebase it simply fails and I get this error message at the same line as before "Thread:1 breakpoint 1.1". I just changed "AnyObject" to "Any"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the literal to the desired type

```
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
  return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser] as Any
}
```

But - no offense – casting up a specific type to something more unspecific is silly. Why not

```
func toDictionary() -> [String:String] {
  return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser]
}
```